# Adjusting query in field calculator in QGIS 3.2?

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator

I have a geopackage file which contains point data with a column of `'depth of cover'` and score.

In the score column I am using the field calculation to create an expression so that any number less than 0.5 in the depth of cover column would be represented as a 1 and anything in between 0.6 to 5.0 would be represented as a 2, and anything greater than 5.1 would be a 3 in the score column.

This is the expression I have used:

```sql
CASE
  WHEN  "Depth of cover" <=0.5 THEN 1
  WHEN  "Depth of cover" >=0.6 <=5.0 THEN 2 
  WHEN  "Depth of cover">=5.1 THEN 3
END
```

I can get the 1 and 3 values to work but not 2.  I know I have the expression wrong at this point because I'm doing a range rather than a less than or greater.

Following on from this if I wanted to change the 1 to a High 2 to medium and 3 to Low how would I do this as I get Column `'High'` not found.

Comment: I think your formula misses an `AND` in the second `WHEN`-clause.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 11):

Try this (I correct bounds too) :

```sql
CASE
 WHEN "Depth of cover" <= 0.5 THEN 1
 WHEN "Depth of cover" > 0.5 AND "Depth of cover" <= 5.0 THEN 2
 WHEN "Depth of cover" > 5.0 THEN 3
 ELSE NULL
END
```

For the second part, create a string field and update it with :

```sql
CASE
 WHEN "Depth of cover" <= 0.5 THEN 'High'
 WHEN "Depth of cover" > 0.5 AND "Depth of cover" <= 5.0 THEN 'Medium'
 WHEN "Depth of cover" > 5.0 THEN 'Low'
 ELSE NULL
END
```